# Bundle pre-populated realm with react native app

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, realm, android-device-monitor

I am attempting to bundle a pre-populated realm with a react native app.

I have followed this, in an attempt to get this working for android. 
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/532

Which advised to put the realm in the assets folder:(android/app/src/main/assets). I have done so:

[image]

However, when I run  Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles() in the contrructor of my base component like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();
  }
```

I get the build error:

[image]

Any help in fixing this so that I can bundle pre-populated realms with an app would be extremely helpful. I have been working on this for quite a few hours now and just can't seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok figured this out for android:

1) In the android/app/src/main/assets folder paste the realm.

2) in index.android.js: Use copyBundledRealmFiles() to move them over:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Realm from 'realm';
import App from './src/App';

const App2 = () => {
  Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();
  return (
    <App />
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SenecaV2', () => App2);
```

then close all terminals and run react-native run-android to rebundle.

You can check if the realm is being compied over by using the command line to go to (on mac)

`library/android/sdk/tools`

then the command `monitor`

this will open up the device monitor. Then, in the device monitor click on file mangager and navgigate to data/data/{packageName}/files and you should see the realm copied over.

If you then want to be able to reference that path in your app use the package:

https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs

To give you the path to the files system:

```
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/{nameOfYourPrePackagedRealmFile}`
```

You can then use this in the new Realm constructors config path property to access the realm.

https://realm.io/docs/javascript/1.0.0/api/Realm.html#path

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!

Comment: Hi, can you direct me to how get pre-populated realm file to start with? Windows + Android

Comment: you can populate it 1) either by doing it manually with the realm browser or 2) algorhymically in the standard way see https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/

Comment: 1) dont have mac 2) docs are lacking or I cant find it or its for ios...

Comment: not worked for me :( populated realm is created in the file directory without data